# Can we use adal-angular for Mobile applications developed using Cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova-plugins, adal

I've used adal-angular for a web based Single page application. Can I use the same library for applications built using Cordova for ADAL Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not recommended, as ADAL JS is designed for handling the SPA case but is not supported for native clients. Furthermore, you'd suffer with sandboxing limitations that aren't strictly necessary when using Cordova. See the preview of our cordova plugin for ADAL instead: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-cordova/

Comment: Well the issue is related to the TOKEN expiry and authorization of the same. I've already referred the above example and able to get the token which cannot be authorized where as the token we get use adal.js and adal-angular,js is authorized. Please help me on this

Comment: I recommend you start another question, given that the library being used is different. You should also make sure that you add details about the failure you are observing.